# How to get current month name in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I need current month name as default perameter name in my ssrs report. How can I get current month name using an ssrs expression?

For example "27-09-2012" would become "September"
and  one more i need....

27-09-2012 to previous month name as well (August)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First question:

```
=MonthName(Month(Fields!datefield.Value))
```

Second question:

```
=MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Today())))
```

I think the second question answer might be something like that, first converting the date to month then subtracting 1 from the month value and then converting it to month name.

Further reading:

- [SSRS Reports get Month name from Month Index or from date](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/ssrs-reports-get-month-name-from-month.html)
- [Converting month number to month name in reporting services](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/d9c4f60d-3961-4e46-960a-e7c86a50f201)

OFF: I would change the date format you are using to `2012-09-27` as it works in every setting and should give you peace of mind when converting date formats.

Comment: but i don't want to use (Fields!datefield.Value). Is there any way to get the date..... like now() or getdate()....

Comment: Try using  =MonthName(Month(today())), tell us if it works. I edited the comment, to get the current date the function is today(), not now().

Comment: Second Question: "=MonthName(Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Today())))", as Sammy said. MonthName() was a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Don't subtract 1 b/c it won't work for January.
Use this:
MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, CDate(Today))))

Answer (score 2):

As a note, I tried the suggestion of =MonthName(Month(today())).  What I would get is #error for whatever field the expression was in.  However, =MonthName(str(Month(today()))) worked for me.  I am unsure of whether or not the MonthName method changed to require a string or if it is some issue with my program.  Just figured I would post this in case anyone else was having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Previous Month i found universal way : =MonthName(Month(CDate(Today()))-1,False) for SEPTEMBER (Full Month Name) 'OR'
=MonthName(Month(CDate(Today()))-1,True) for SEP (Short Month Name)